# CSS dynamically added elements match content size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating elements with a small amount of text in them and I want each one to be the size of the text + some padding

```
cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #323232;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: 300;
  min-height: 48px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
```

This works fine only if there is one element. However, if there are 2 or more elements, they all resize to the width of the largest element which I do not want.

https://jsfiddle.net/zbrmLdwv/

Comment: Can't understand it but try if `display: inline-block` can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css, add:

```
float:left;
clear:left;
```

This makes the element "shrinkwrap" so it wraps the text automatically.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbrmLdwv/)

Answer (score 0):

The `width` problem you are facing, is maybe due to their `display` property. Please add

```
p{ display: inline-block }
```

Replace `p` with the correct element selector, and check if the problem solved.

Comment: This works but it places the elements inline which I don't want I want them in a colum